# Azure CI Pipeline runs WPF Application in background

Tags: azure-devops

I have create Azure CI Pipeline using Classic Editor where I have Command Line task which open WPF Application, now the issue is when I configure Agent as Service this WPF Application runs in background not showing interface on front, but the same task is running properly when Agent is not running as service.
I require to open WPF Application when running Agent as Service.

I have also tried configuring agent with User Account but still facing same issue. WPF application runs in background. In task manager its showing application running but not appearing on screen.

For e.g :- Below Command I am writting to open exe in Command Line Task of azure devops CI pipeline.

**cd /D D:\Application_Build\Executable

start Sample.exe**

Above command works properly when agent is not running as service, but fail when configure agent as service.

Comment: Due to Windows session isolation, it is impossible to show that WPF app when the agent is running as service.

Answer (score 0):

> Above command works properly when agent is not running as service, but fail when configure agent as service.

Based on your description, when you run the Agent as interactive mode. Agent will run using the account of the user who run the Agent.  Then it will have enough permission to run the script.

When you run the Agent as service, it will use the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account.

The permissions of this account are restricted. So it could cause this issue.

You could create an agent with the admin account or the your user account.

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\adminccount --windowsLogonPassword Password
```

On the other hand, you could navigate to **local system -> Service** and find the running agent service.

Then you could change the `logon account` as admin account.

[image: agent]

Here is a doc about  [create agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#choose-interactive-or-service-mode).

Comment: I have tried configuring agent with User Account but still facing same issue. WPF application runs in background. In task manager its showing application running but not appearing on screen.